# Calculate the de Rham cohomology of $S^1 \times S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, spheres, de-rham-cohomology

For our homework sheet it says: calculate the de Rham cohomology of $M = S^1 \times S^2$ or check a book if you are unsure. And then it continues. Since I didn't find the calculation in a book I wanted to ask here.

It is clear that $H_{dR}^0(M) = \mathbb{R}$, as $M$ is connected. And since $M$ has dimension $3$, that $H_{dR}^k(M) = 0$ if $k >3$.

Comment: I think this is an easy application of the Kunneth formula.

Comment: Do you already know Poincaré's duality stating that $H^k(M) \simeq H^{n-k}(M)$ if $M$ is $n$ dimensional? If so, you are left to only compute $H^1(S^1\times S^2)$!

Comment: Sadly I know neither of them...prerequisites for the course were just Riemannian geometry. But seeing a calculation of $H^1(S^1 \times S^2)$ would also be helpful. I read that Mayer-Vietoris can also be used in cohomology somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will be answering this question using only the Mayer Vietoris sequence. We can cover $S^1\times S^2$ with two open sets $U$ and $V$ which are homeomorphic to $(0,1)\times S^2$ which are both homotopic to $S^2$ and thus will have the same cohomology. We also have that $U\cap V$ will be homotopic to the disjoint union of two spheres. We also use a property of disjoint unions which is that for any set of manifolds $M_k$ we have that the DeRham cohomology of the disjoint union is given by
\begin{equation*}
H^i(\;\bigsqcup_{k\in I} M_k)\cong\bigoplus_{k\in I}H^i(M_k)
\end{equation*}
In our case we simply have that for all $i\in \mathbb{N}$ $H^i(S^2\sqcup S^2)\cong H^i(S^2)\oplus H^i(S^2)$. The sequence is non trivial in two segments

\begin{equation*}
0\rightarrow H^0(S^1\times S^2)\rightarrow H^0(S^2)\oplus H^0(S^2)\rightarrow H^0(S^2\sqcup S^2)\rightarrow H^1(S^1\times S^2)
\rightarrow 0
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
0\rightarrow H^2(S^1\times S^2)\rightarrow H^2(S^2)\oplus H^2(S^2)\rightarrow H^2(S^2\sqcup S^2)\rightarrow H^3(S^1\times S^2)
\rightarrow 0
\end{equation*}
By linear algebra reasons gives us that
$H^0(S^1\times S^2)\cong H^1(S^1\times S^2)$ and $H^2(S^1\times S^2)\cong H^3(S^1\times S^2)$. But we have that since $S^1\times S^2$ is connected $H^0(S^1\times S^2)\cong \mathbb{R}$ By the fact that $S^1\times S^2$ is compact and orientable you can use Poincare duality and I get that $H^3(S^1\times S^2)\cong H^0(S^1\times S^2)$. Which gives us that the first four groups are of dimension $1$ and the rest are trivial.

If you have not seen Poincare duality you can notice that since it is compact and orientable it has a volume form $H^3(S^1\times S^2)$ has dimension at least $1$ but it is isomorphic to $H^2(S^1\times S^2)$ which injects into $H^2(S^2)\oplus H^2(S^2)$ which has dimension $2$. So the for $2$ and $3$ the cohomology groups will have both dimension $1$ or both dimension $2$. If you study the inclusion maps you might be able to improve this result without using the poincare lemma.

Another way is to see that you can decompose $S^1\times S^2$ into two opens sets $U$ and $V$ which are homeomorphic to $D^2\times S^1$ and so they will be homotopic to $S^1$ and their intersection will be homotopic to $S^1\times S^1$. Using the fact that $H^1(S^1\times S^1)\cong \mathbb{R}^2$ we have the following sequence
\begin{equation*}
0\rightarrow H^1(S^1\times S^2)\rightarrow H^1(S^1)\oplus H^1(S^1)\rightarrow H^1(S^1\times S^1)\rightarrow H^2(S^1\times S^2)\rightarrow 0
\end{equation*}
This is because the boundary map $\delta:H^0(U\cap V)\rightarrow H^1(S^1\times S^2)$ will have to be the zero map.
Since $H^1(S^1)\oplus H^1(S^1)\cong H^1(S^1\times S^1)$
and we get that $H^1(S^1\times S^3)$ will have to have the same dimension as $H^2(S^1\times S^2)$. By using this you avoid having to use Poincare duality

If needed I am willing to clarify some steps which are not obvious

Comment: Why is $H^3(\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{S}^2)\cong H^2(\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{S}^2)$?

Comment: @Laz By the second part of the long exact sequence and is the same reason why $H^0(S^1\times S^2)\cong H^1(S^1\times S^2)$. This is due to a result that is essentially of linear algebra. The two middle objects in the sequence have same dimension and so the two outer ones will have to have same dimension. In general given an exact sequence of vector spaces $V_i\rightarrow V_{i+1}$ that starts and ends with a $0$ we have that $\sum_{i\leq n}(-1)^i dim(V_i)=0$. You can use this if you want.

Comment: So, it is a dimensionality argument. I just wanted to pint that out since this is not the same as being isomorphic by a natural map in the MV sequence, which allows you to give explicit generators. Fine.

Comment: @Laz Yes for all I know there is no natural isomorphism between the second and third cohomology group